# In Visual Basic 2010 - System.Net showing error on certain kind of web links

Tags: vb.net, url, razor

My aim was to create a small application which when given a website link such as

`http://digikey.com/product-detail/en/ATF1502ASV-15JU44/ATF1502ASV-15JU44-ND/1008571/`

it will extract datas from its Page Source like

Manufacture PartNumber
Item Description etc

I used this code to get the page source

```
Dim PartURL As String = "http://digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM567CN/LM567CN-ND/2607028"
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(PartURL)
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New     System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
TextBox1.Text = sourcecode
```

But i found something out of my knowledge
It will access and get source code from this link

http://digikey.com/product-detail/en/ATF1502ASV-15JU44/ATF1502ASV-15JU44-ND/1008571`

but will not access this

http://digikey.com/product-detail/en/PIC18F45K20-I%2FPT/PIC18F45K20-I%2FPT-ND/1228485

I observed a lot and found that the difference between the two link was that first one's part number was ATF1502ASV-15JU44-ND and second ones was PIC18F45K20-I/PT-ND,
Former one doesnt have "/" in the name but second one has it,
so inorder to differentiate the "/" in partnumber from that of the normal weblinks "/" they put "%2F" replacing it in the name
So they changed

PIC18F45K20-I/PT-ND to

PIC18F45K20-I%2FPT-ND

I dont know whether my inference is correct
But the 2nd link always shows error and sourcecode cant be accessed

And also when i get the source code what i do is
search for a particular string "Manufacturer Part Number" in the source code and then from that line i find the Part number

Iam sure there will be better efficient easier ways for this
Please help me with that too

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for VBA

```
Sub xmlHttp()
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim strVal As String
    Dim URl As String

    URl = "http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM567CN/LM567CN-ND/2607028"
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", URl, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Set thele = html.getElementsByTagName("th")

    For Each i In thele

        If i.innerHTML = "Manufacturer" Then
            strVal = i.NextSibling.innerText
            MsgBox "Manufacturer :" & strVal
        ElseIf i.innerHTML = "Manufacturer Part Number" Then
            strVal = i.NextSibling.innerText
            MsgBox "Manufacturer Part Number : " & strVal
        ElseIf i.innerHTML = "Description" Then
            strVal = i.NextSibling.innerText
            MsgBox "Description :" & strVal
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```